# Android UI Layout With Tabs and Fragments

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I am attempting to create a layout similar to the current Facebook layout, where the tabs used for navigation are always visible, and navigation occurs inside the tabs themselves. Has anyone seen this or know of where I might look to figure this out? I have gotten to the point where I can replace the fragments inside of the individual tabs, but I am unable to figure out how exactly to update the action bar so that a back button exists as well as update the back button action depending on which tab they are in.

Comment: In Fragment call getActivity().getActionbar() and set it's title.

Comment: Setting the title is not the problem, its updating the action bar depending on the back stack, as each tab should have its own back stack.